# Form gets submitted even tho not all inputs are filled, except the flatpickr input fields (startdate, enddate)

Tags: javascript, html, flatpickr

My form gets submitted with running validationprocess, even tho not all input fields are set to get trough the process. I hope this makes any sense.
The form gets submitted with the input fields startdate and enddate set.
I cant figure out what the problem is that the validation just ignores the other inputs values.

**My code:**

```js
configStartDate = {
  altInput: true,
  altFormat: "j F, Y H:i",
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
  minDate: "today",
  enableTime: true,
  time_24hr: true,
  firstDayOfWeek: 1, // Monday
  onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    // Set minDate for endDatePicker to start from the selected date of startDatePicker
    if (selectedDates[0] !== undefined) {
      endDatePicker.set("minDate", selectedDates[0]);
    }
    // Check for empty input
    if (selectedDates.length === 0) {
      instance.altInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
      console.log("Date picker is empty");
    } else {
      instance.altInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
      console.log("Date picker is not empty");
    }
  },
};

configEndDate = {
  altInput: true,
  altFormat: "j F, Y H:i",
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
  minDate: "today",
  enableTime: true,
  time_24hr: true,
  firstDayOfWeek: 1, // Monday
  onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    if (selectedDates[0] !== undefined) {
      startDatePicker.set("maxDate", selectedDates[0]);
    }
    if (selectedDates.length === 0) {
      instance.altInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
      console.log("Date picker is empty");
    } else {
      instance.altInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
      console.log("Date picker is not empty");
    }
  },
};

const startDatePicker = flatpickr("#input_start_date", configStartDate);
const endDatePicker = flatpickr("#input_end_date", configEndDate);

// Validating inputs with bootstrap validation (user-sided)
// console.log("bis zur Validierung gekommen");
const booking_form = document.getElementById("booking_form");
const nameInput = document.getElementById("input_name");
const first_nameInput = document.getElementById("input_first_name");
const emailInput = document.getElementById("input_email");
const telInput = document.getElementById("input_tel");
const addressInput = document.getElementById("input_address");
const address_nrInput = document.getElementById("input_address_nr");
const cityInput = document.getElementById("input_city");
const zipInput = document.getElementById("input_zip");
const stateInput = document.getElementById("input_state");
const start_dateInput = document.getElementById("input_start_date");
const end_dateInput = document.getElementById("input_end_date");
const checkboxInput = document.getElementById("input_check");

function validateBookingInputs() {
  // Get input values
  const nameValue = nameInput.value.trim();
  const first_nameValue = first_nameInput.value.trim();
  const emailValue = emailInput.value.trim();
  // const passwordValue = passwordInput.value.trim();
  const telValue = telInput.value.trim();
  const addressValue = addressInput.value.trim();
  const address_nrValue = address_nrInput.value.trim();
  const cityValue = cityInput.value.trim();
  const zipValue = zipInput.value.trim();
  const stateValue = stateInput.value.trim();
  // const startDateValue = start_dateInput;
  // const endDateValue = end_dateInput;

  // Regex Patterns
  const emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/;
  // const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/;
  // Swiss Phone Number Regex (Ausbaufaehig)
  const telRegex = /(\b(0041|0)|\B\+41)(\s?\(0\))?(\s)?[1-9]{2}(\s)?[0-9]{3}(\s)?[0-9]{2}(\s)?[0-9]{2}\b/;
  const address_nrRegex = /^[1-9](?:\d{2}(?:,\d{3})+|\d*)$/;
  // Normal Zip Code Regex (Ausbaufaehig)
  const zipRegex = /^[1-9]\d{3}$/;
  // German Date Regex
  const dateRegex = /^20[2-9][0-9]-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(([0-2][1-9])|3[0-1])\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])\:[0-5][0-9]$/;

  // Validate inputs
  let isValid = true;

  if (nameValue === "") {
    nameInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    nameInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    nameInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (first_nameValue === "") {
    first_nameInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    first_nameInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    first_nameInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (!emailRegex.test(emailValue)) {
    emailInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    emailInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    emailInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (!telRegex.test(telValue)) {
    telInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    telInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    telInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (addressValue === "") {
    addressInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    addressInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    addressInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (!address_nrRegex.test(address_nrValue)) {
    address_nrInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    address_nrInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    address_nrInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (cityValue === "") {
    cityInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    cityInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    cityInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (!zipRegex.test(zipValue)) {
    zipInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    zipInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    zipInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (stateValue === "Choose...") {
    stateInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    stateInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    stateInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  // Startdate if empty check
  if (startDatePicker.input.value === "") {
    startDatePicker.input.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    startDatePicker.input.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    start_dateInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  // Enddate if empty check
  if (endDatePicker.input.value === "") {
    endDatePicker.input.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    endDatePicker.input.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    endDatePicker.input.value.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  if (!checkboxInput.checked) {
    checkboxInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    checkboxInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    checkboxInput.classList.add("is-valid");
  }

  console.log("validInputs are valid");
  return isValid;
}

booking_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  if (!validateBookingInputs()) {
    console.log("validateInputs nicht korrekt");
    // Prevent form submission if inputs are invalid
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    console.log("validateInputs korrekt");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/themes/airbnb.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<div class="con-left">
  <form class="row g-3 px-4 pt-2 pb-4" novalidate action="" method="post" id="booking_form">
    <h1>booking system</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_name" name="input_name" placeholder="Name" required>
      <label>Last name</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your last name!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_first_name" name="input_first_name" placeholder="Vorname" required>
      <label>First name</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your first name!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input_email" name="input_email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <label>E-mail address</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your e-mail address! For example - "example@email.com".</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_tel" name="input_tel" placeholder="Telefon" required>
      <label>Telephone</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter phone number as 0041 xx ..., +41 xx ... or 0xx!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_address" name="input_address" placeholder="Strasse" required>
      <label>Address</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your address!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input_address_nr" name="input_address_nr" placeholder="Strassennummer" required pattern="[0-9].{3,}">
      <label>additional address</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your additional address!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_city" name="input_city" placeholder="Ort" required>
      <label>Hometown</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your hometown!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_zip" name="input_zip" placeholder="PLZ" required>
      <label>Zip code</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Zip code must be at least 3 digits long!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-1 form-floating">
      <select class="form-select" id="input_state" name="input_state" placeholder="Land" required>
        <option selected disabled>Choose...</option>
      </select>
      <label>Choose country</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your country!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_start_date" name="input_start_date" placeholder="Buchungsanfang" required>
      <label>Start of booking</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Choose the start of your booking!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-1 form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_end_date" name="input_end_date" placeholder="Buchungsende" required>
      <label>End of booking</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Select the end of your booking!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 mb-2">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="" id="input_check" required />
      <label class="form-check-label">Agree to Terms of Use and Privacy Policy</label>
      <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy!</div>
    </div>

    <div class=" d-grid col-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submit">Book apartment</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Help is appreciated.

I tried to log the process, but the form reloads the page before I can read what gets logged into the console.

Comment: In your dev tools, in the Console, click the Settings wheel and check "Preserve log" now you can see what happens.

It is most probably an JavaScript error. And if so, then the form submits... and the page reloads.